# Storing a counter

Tags: jsf

In a JSF application I have a session scoped bean that has various getters and setters for several web pages, and when a visitor click the "Submit" button, the entered values from the pages are sent to an output file for later processing with another application.

I wish to keep track of the number of times data have been written to a file on a particular day, and although I will eventually probably use a database, I wish to store the counter in a place that is updated by all people who visit the page.  My understanding is that if I store it as a static int in the managed bean, the value will not be preserved in a different session.  I have a non-bean class that stores some utility methods, such as handling dates, and my question is that will a non-bean class store a static variable that can be accessed from any session, and be used to keep track of information, such as counting submits?

Many thanks in advance for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

> *My understanding is that if I store it as a static int in the managed bean, the value will not be preserved in a different session.*

That's incorrect. Static variables are applicationwide. They are not tied to the instance, but to the class. A class is loaded only once during application's lifetime. You'd also have figured that yourself with a rather simple experiment.

Your only concern may be threadsafety. Make use of [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead of `int` so that you don't risk race conditions during incrementals.

#### See also:

- [Basic Java tutorial - Understanding instance and class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Many thanks, that is very helpful indeed, and I learned something new, as I never heard of atomic classes before.

Answer (score 0):

Any static field will accomplish your goal as long as you don't restart the server, even the one in your managed bean on the session scope. The static variable belongs to the class, not the instance and the class of your managed bean is loaded only once by the JVM. Since you will access that static variable potentially from multiple threads you need to synchronize when you modify its value.